# "familiar to" vs. "familiar with"

Tags: word-usage

Cambridge Dictionary gives [these definitions and examples](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/familiar) about "familiar"

> easy to recognize because of being seen before
>
> > The street was familiar to me.
>
> to know something or someone well
>
> > I'm sorry, I'm not familiar with your poetry.

In the following context, which one should I use?

> British English **is familiar to** Chinese kids, since they are taught in school with British English.

or

> Chinese kids **are familiar with** British English, since they are taught in school with British English.

Could someone please give a hint? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use whichever sentence you wish; both are grammatical.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it depends on whether you are talking about the object or experience, or the person experiencing it:

> The street was familiar **to** me <=> I was familiar **with** the street.
>
> Your poetry is not familiar **to** me <=> I am not familiar **with** your poetry.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. In the example of British English, both sentences are grammatically correct and mean the same thing, right?

Comment: They're both grammatically correct, and mean pretty much the same thing. I wouldn't say they're precisely the same, because one is a statement about my knowledge, and the other about the object in my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Both are grammatically correct. I think familiar with is used actively while familiar to is used passively.
He is familiar with me. I am familiar to him

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This also doesn't really add anything new to the existing answer.